# SQL count(*) issues with join on multiple tables in mysql involving an outer join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, lets say t1, t2, t3 with columns as

```
 t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3 
 t2.c4, t2.c1, t2.c5
 t3.c6, t3.c4
```

t1.c1, t2.c4 and t3.c6 are primary, autoincrements fields of their respective tables.

t2.c1 is a foreign key in t2 referring to t1.c1 in t1

t3.c4 is a foreign key in t3 referring to t2.c4 in t2

I want to get the following output for any given value of t2.c5 (say X)

**SORRY - Mistake in output columns!**

I want output to be

```
t2.c4, t1.c2, count
```

**and not**

```
t2.c1, t1.c2, count
```

where count is the number of records in t3 for the given value of t2.c5 and must be zero if no record exists where t2.c5=X and t3.c4=t2.c4

Can this be done in one select query?

Here is sample data:

**Table: t1**

```
  +------+-------+------+
  | c1   | c2    | c3   |
  +------+-------+------+
  |    1 | 11111 |  111 |
  |    2 | 22222 |  222 |
  |    3 | 33333 |  333 |
  +------+-------+------+
```

**Table: t2**

```
  +------+------+------+
  | c4   | c1   | c5   |
  +------+------+------+
  |    1 |    1 |   11 |
  |    2 |    1 |   11 |
  |    3 |    2 |   11 |
  |    4 |    2 |   12 |
  |    5 |    3 |   12 |
  |    6 |    2 |   12 |
  +------+------+------+
```

**Table: t3**

```
  +------+------+
  | c6   | c4   |
  +------+------+
  |    1 |    1 |
  |    2 |    1 |
  |    3 |    5 |
  +------+------+
```

For `t2.c5=11`, the output is

```
    +-------------------+
     t2.c4 | t1.c2| Count
    +-------------------+
      1    | 11111| 2
      2    | 11111| 0
      3    | 22222| 0
    +-------------------+
```

For `t2.c5=12`, the output is

```
    +-------------------+
     t2.c4 | t1.c2| Count
    +-------------------+
      4    | 22222| 0
      5    | 33333| 1
      6    | 22222| 0
```

Comment: The title reads *"SQL count(\*) issues"* -- what are the issues? You didn't post any query.

Comment: @axiac I am unable to get the query in a single select. I can get it in two selects in a scripting language which has mysql interface.

Comment: We would like to see these two separate selects so that we can point you to the correct direction.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Please see update with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @axiac Please see update in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t2.c4, t1.c2, COUNT(t3.c6) 
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.c4 = t2.c4
WHERE t2.c5 = '11'
GROUP BY t2.c4, t1.c2
```

**Output:**

```
c4  c2  count
-------------
1   11111   2
2   11111   0
3   22222   0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a617d7/5)

With this query:

```
SELECT t2.c4, t1.c2, COUNT(t3.c6) as count
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.c4 = t2.c4
WHERE t2.c5 = '12'
GROUP BY t2.c4, t1.c2
```

output is:

```
c4  c2      count
-----------------
4   22222   0
5   33333   1
6   22222   0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a617d7/6)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for my mistake. Please see update in the question along with sample data and expected output.

Comment: Please help! I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  t2.c1, t1.c2, count(*)
FROM t1 inner join t2 using (c1)
inner join t3 using (c4)
GROUP BY t2.c5, t2.c1, t1.c2
```

Whats confusing here is that you want to select t2.c1, t1.c2
 for any value of t2.c5.

You will have to decide either grouping by all three columns as shown above, or really grouping by t2.c5, and just showing any value of t2.c2, t1.c2 , which will require using some aggregate function on them. For example:

```
SELECT  max(t2.c1) c2, max(t1.c2) c2, count(*)
FROM t1 inner join t2 using (c1)
inner join t3 using (c4)
GROUP BY t2.c5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for my mistake. Please see update in the question along with sample data and expected output.